# Django can't create new object in UserProfile

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have UserProfile like below:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    formats = str(instance.id) + 'moolak' + '.' + filename.split('.')[-1]
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), str(instance.id)+'/avatar', formats)
    return path


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=get_image_path)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=4, blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(3), MaxValueValidator(99)])
    birth_day = models.DateField(default=date(2015, 1, 1))
    location = CountryField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX, default='N')
    about_me = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    call_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id is not None:
            this = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=self.id)
            if this.avatar != self.avatar:
                this.avatar.delete(save=True)
            super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.user
```

And I have Setting.py like below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.UserProfile'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

When I try to create an object by means of `create` or other syntaxes.
I give the following error:

```
No UserProfile matches the given query.
```

But when I remove `avatar` from UserProfile and its corresponded codes, it works.
I think Django can't save images! can you help me, I am a newbie.
I want to images be saved to:

```
 `current-project-directory/static/media/images/avatar`
```

Comment: Path does not exists

Comment: @Gocht I annexed some new explanation above. Can you help me more! TNX

Comment: `upload_to` spects a folder path, that will be appended to your `media` so you also need a media folder. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)